# parse multiple web pages simultaneously

Tags: python, parsing, multiprocessing, lxml

i often require to parse/scrape information from internet web pages. I am using `lxml` and `requests` for the purpose. Almost in all cases, the information is sequential in nature, like bunch of stock related information or date wise information. Currently, I run a list comprehension to run the loop. I am wondering if there a way in which I can parse multiple pages at same time? I know about multiprocessing/forking but i would appreciate some simpler solution. here is my sample code

```
[lxml.html.fromstring(requests.get(i).content).xpath("//tr//td//text()") for i in ("some_list of url addresses")]
```

This works fine but I want to be able to parse more than one (maybe upto 8) webpages in a single run of the loop , somewhat akin to opening multiple webpages in the browser.

Comment: Look into scrapy.

Answer (score 0):

I know that you've written that you're aware of multiprocessing.
But you also stated that you search an easy solution and I think threading provides such an easy solution.

```
import requests
import lxml
import threading
        
urls = ["sample.com", "sample2.com", "sample3.com"]


def scrape(url):
    return lxml.html.fromstring(requests.get(i).content).xpath("//tr//td//text()")

for url in urls:
    if threading.active_count() < 8:
        threading.Thread(target=scrape, args=(url,)).start()
```